# How to create a tree table html file usin below JSON file

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I am trying to create tree table html file using primeng. The Html file should able to render below JSON file .

Below is the 
**Json** response.

```
{
      "data": [
        {
          "data": {
            "Briname": "Aamir",
            "aantalPersonen": "122"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "data": {
                "Vestiging": "Ranchi",
                "aantalPersonen": "102"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "data": {
                    "Singalcode": "4",
                    "aantalPersonen": "15"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "data": {
                    "Singalcode": "5",
                    "aantalPersonen": "10"
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "data": {
                "Vestiging": "Bangalore",
                "aantalPersonen": "82"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "data": {
                    "Singalcode": "6",
                    "aantalPersonen": "15"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "data": {
            "Briname": "Abhinav",
            "aantalPersonen": "122"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "data": {
                "Vestiging": "Bangalore",
                "aantalPersonen": "102"
              },
              "children": [
                {
                  "data": {
                    "Singalcode": "4",
                    "aantalPersonen": "15"
                  }
                }
              ]
           }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here the parent having "Briname" as key data element name and children node having "vestging and "Singalcode" as data element.

How we can achieve this using tree table?

**HTML**:

```
<p-treeTable [value]="files2" [columns]="cols" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode1" (onNodeSelect)="nodeSelect($event)">
  <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowNode let-rowData="rowData" let-columns="columns" >
    <tr [ttSelectableRow]="rowNode">
      <td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index">
        <p-treeTableToggler [rowNode]="rowNode" *ngIf="i == 0"></p-treeTableToggler>
        {{rowData[col.field]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </ng-template>
</p-treeTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to display first property of `data`

Let declare `_object = Object;` in ts file

Then display first property on HTML file

```
{{ rowData[_object.keys(rowData)[0]] }}
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnq1yi)

Comment: Because you cannot use class 'Object' on HTML but can assign it into _object

Comment: can you help to map it using observable map function : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275822/how-to-observable-map-nested-json-objects-with-different-property-names-angula

Comment: I remember i answered this question. Is it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54200809/5737571

Comment: But how we can approach through observable map function. Also in html  , we are using onject in rownode to show values, can we show data using rownode.name

Answer (score 0):

I think property names need to be remapped and fixed.

like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "data": {
        "name": "Briname: Aamir",
        "aantalPersonen": "122"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "data": {
            "name": "Vestiging: Ranchi",
            "aantalPersonen": "102"
          },
...
```

Comment: Then in this case BRINname and vestiging is also coming in User interface. How can i maaped nested json message to table tree Json format

Comment: How can i mapped the preoperty names

Comment: how can we mapped the property names in this case