# Tree table html from json

Tags: json, angular, primeng, primeng-treetable

I have a JSON format and I am using primeng and want to use it a tree table structure (Html file).

JSON:

```
 {
      brinname: "Aamir",
      aantalPersonen: "122",
      signalenVestiging: [
        {
          vestiging: "Ranchi",
          aantalPersonen: "102",
          signalenCode: [
            {
            signaalCode: "4",
            aantalPersonen: "15"
           },
          {
            signaalCode: "5",
            aantalPersonen: "15"
          } ]
        }, {
          vestiging: "Bangalore",
          aantalPersonen: "82",
          signalenCode: [
            {
              signaalCode: "6",
              aantalPersonen: "15"
            },
            {
              signaalCode: "7",
              aantalPersonen: "15"
            } ]
        } ]

    },
    {
      brinname: "Abhinav",
      aantalPersonen: "122",
      signalenVestiging: [
        {
          vestiging: "Bangalore",
          aantalPersonen: "102",
          signalenCode: [ {
            signaalCode: "7",
            aantalPersonen: "15"
          }]
        } ]
```

Can someone explain to me how can I achieve the above request? I am getting a lot of confusion to create a tree table html structure.

Comment: Guys ! any solution :)

Comment: This site is not a free coding service. Please read on How to ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Explain: You need to clone all element's property to `node`'s data property by `Object.keys(element).forEach` - exclude array type property (`signalenVestiging`, `signalenCode`). Then add elements in array type property to `node`'s children array. (Sorry for my bad english)

You can use below code

```
this.jsonData.forEach(element => {
      let tmp: any = {
        data: {},
        children: []
      };
      Object.keys(element).forEach(prop => {
        if (prop != 'signalenVestiging') {
          tmp.data[prop] = element[prop];
        } else {
          element[prop].forEach(c1 => {
            let tmp1: any = {
              data: {},
              children: []
            };
            Object.keys(c1).forEach(prop1 => {
              if (prop1 != 'signalenCode') {
                tmp1.data[prop1] = c1[prop1];
              } else {
                c1[prop1].forEach(c2 => {
                  let clone = $.extend(true, {}, c2);
                  tmp1.children.push({ data: clone });
                });
              }
            });
            tmp.children.push(tmp1);
          });
        }
      });
      this.data.push(tmp);
    });
```

Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnq1yi)

Comment: Demo is throwing error and not loading the Userinterface

Comment: Can we achieve this using observable , pipe or transform

Comment: Also can you please explain how you have done it so i can understand it